# How to add a new line when adding something to a variable

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, variables

I have this:

```
data.data.message = 'User created';
app.successMsg = data.data.message + '...Redirecting';
```

And I want to add a line before the `...Redirecting`. I've tried `\n`, `\r`, both together but it's not working. I've also read some articles here but they all tell them to use the `\n` and `\r` but it's not working for me. I'm just learning so be patient please.

---------------------------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------

When I use `'<br />.... Redirecting'` this happens:

[image: The <br /> tag appears]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may use `<br/>` tag to get a new line.
apart of that, you may use any block element(e.g. div) to show it to other line. it actually puts it in another element and block element is always rendered in new line so data goes to next line. you can then apply css to it as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it in a browser, then my guess is it's rendered as HTML. HTML ignores newlines, and puts everything on the same line. So you could either put the above text between `<pre>` brackets, or echo our `<br />` where you want a new line. Hope that helps.

Comment: Well actually it does but it doesn't really answer my question. I could just use another div and make it appear there but I want it to be in the same div. Thanks anyways!

Comment: `<br />` has nothing to do with `div`s. And could you inspect the page source to see if the newline is rendered at all? I'm kinda struggling with what it is that you want.

Comment: What I meant was that I could just adjust the html code so that the '...Redirecting' is insert in a new line. But I want to know which '\' command I can use to write that new line in the variable.

Comment: Again: any '\' commands WILL write a new line. If you look at the page source, you'll see that there's a new line there. But HTML doesn't work that way. If you want "...Redirecting" to show on a new line, then either put `<br />` in front of it, or put it between `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Try replacing "...Redirecting" with "<br />...Redirecting" and post the results here.

Comment: I thought you were talking about the html code, to write the <br/> inside the html.

Comment: It's not working, I'll edit the question to show you what appears when adding the `<br />`